# Clean way to parse a string (bunch of coordinates) into a list of floats in python?

Tags: python

I was writing code that was looking uglier and uglier to take this string:

```
"69.766357,21.026979 70.303459,14.286892 71.782379,15.119740 71.216835,22.351538"
```

and parse it into a list that looked like this:

```
pos = [[69.766357,21.026979],[70.303459,14.286892],[71.782379,15.119740],[71.216835,22.351538],[69.766357,21.026979]]
```

Latest code:

```
#shave off the first point because we need to add it back in to close poly
firstVal = elem.text.split()
firstVal = firstVal[0].split(',')


for i in elem.text.split():
    smallList = []
    for j in i.split(','):
        smallList.append(float(j))                      
    finalVals.append(smallList)

smallList=[]
smallList.append(float(firstVal[0]))
smallList.append(float(firstVal[1]))
finalVals.append(smallList)

print finalVals
```

This is the best I could come up with.

Comment: What you are doing is pretty straightforward. What you are expecting is - on the other hand - isn't so :) Can you please explain what you are looking for. Shorter code? Using a library?

Comment: If your code is already working, it might be better to ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  I'd also recommend posting the code you are currently using so we can point out places to improve.

Comment: I had no idea codereview stackexchange even existed, good resource and thank you for the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test = "69.766357,21.026979 70.303459,14.286892 71.782379,15.119740 71.216835,22.351538"

print([[float(j) for j in i.split(',')] for i in test.split()])
```

Comment: Posted code as per others requests, but heavily based on this answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a clean pythonic way for what you are looking for, called list comprehension explained [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)
you need to do two list comprehensions for what you need as below:

```
pos_string = "69.766357,21.026979 70.303459,14.286892 71.782379,15.119740 71.216835,22.351538"
pos = []
pos = [[float(lat_long) for lat_long in position.split(',')] for position in pos_string.split(' ')]
```

Comment: ty for the link, I had no idea what this was called.

Comment: your welcome (: @codejoy